# When I try to run Nextcloud and wordpress at the same time on Centos7, it only shows the nextcloud "access through untrusted domain" screen

Tags: wordpress, nextcloud

I have been running a wordpress server for a while now. I have three sites all with different domains, and I decided to also install nextcloud. Now though, when I try to access the Wordpress sites on any domain, it just shows "access through untrusted domain". It is httpd and running the newest version of all the software. There is no SSL, but there is virtual hosting set up. Is there a way to turn this off so that nextcloud comes through on "nc.example.com" but not "example.com" too?

Im really new to this stuff so the super complicated answers on goodle weren't helping much.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately nextcloud tells you how you can fix this right in the error message:

[image: access through untrusted domain]

Lets analyze the shown error:

Note that it tells the error (Access through untrusted domain), what to do as user (contact your administrator) as well as what to do if you are the servers administrator (edit the "trusted_domains" setting in config/config.php).

There is even a link to the [documentation](https://docs.nextcloud.com/) for further information.

The fix conveniently is exactly as described in the error message:

> edit the "trusted_domains" setting in [your-nextcloud-webroot]/config/config.php

**Example:**

```
  'trusted_domains' => 
  array (
    0 => 'somedomain.xyz:5000',
    1 => 'intern.somedomain.xyz',
    2 => 'asdf.somedomain.xyz',
  ),
```

Regarding using subdomains for different virtual hosts, you need to specify the subdomain in the `ServerName` directive of the site config file in `/etc/httpd/conf.d`.

**Example config file:**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName example.com
    ServerAlias www.example.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/example.com/public_html

    <Directory /var/www/example.com/public_html>
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/example.com-error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/httpd/example.com-access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```